# Learn Python Hard Way Exercise 40 Class Query

Tags: python, object, self

Please see the questions below -

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                   "I don't want to get sued",
                   "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family",
                        "With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

1. In both the def, I see lyrics (line 3, 5 and 6). Why? What is really happening there?
2. The name of the class is Song. On line 8 and 11, there is "Song" on the right side of the variable. Why? I really don't get it.
3. Put the lyrics in a separate variable, then pass that variable to the class to use instead. How would I do that?

This is very important for me, as I just started OOP. Please be patient with me, and answer the above questions.

Comment: This question fails to show a minimal understanding of Python. Voted to close.

Comment: We should _really_ have line numbers on the right of a code sample.

Comment: Have you actually read Zed's explanation of what is happening? He is usually very clear.

Comment: I am learning from Learn Python The Hard Way guys. As far as I understand class, it's like a blueprint from which you can create objects. Or something to the effect.

Comment: So what do you think calling `Song(...)` then does?

Comment: @Daniel, yes I have read his explanation. I understood it. But he doesn't explain the above.

Comment: @SocialCoder: what, like the sentence *The way you do this is you call the class like it's a function, like this:* in that chapter? It is all explained right there, read more carefully, then re-read again.

Comment: As far as I understand, Song is the class, and below we are calling an instance of it. Hmm, I think I am getting it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, linking to the [original example](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html#a-first-class-example) is a good idea. I am using line numbers from the original example.

1. Lines 1 to 8 define a **class** called Song. A class is exactly like a blueprint for making a new object. Every function that you add to a class will be added to the object when you make the object.
2. `Song` is on the right side on line 10 and 14 because you are making new Song objects, and putting them in variables. You don't even need to put the Song object inside a variable. The following would work just fine:

   `Song(["Do","Re","Mi"]).sing_me_a_song()`
3. What is the difference between this:

   `print("Hi!")`

   And this?

   `message = "Hi!"`

   `print(message)`

   In the one you pass a value directly, and in the other you pass a variable that contains the value. Just like `"Hi!"` is a value, `["Do","Re","Mi"]` is a value too. How would you pass the second value to a new Song object?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, and not being like the others. Thanks really.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Remember that there are many Python tutorials and books out there. If one isn't clear, try another tutorial about the same topic. I recommend the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/). Even more important, **try things** to see what works or doesn't work. I think that's the big reason the question was put on hold - you didn't show that you tried anything first.

Comment: Many months later, I'd just like to say thanks for this answer. It actually helped with the exercise (Learn Python the Hard Way can be confusing, it makes you type things out but often just moves on without explaining why). The comments up there on the original question are unhelpful - especially to Python beginners like myself.

Comment: You're welcome! =<^_^>=